# How will Heuristic effect the Dikstras algorithm to make it a A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, heuristics

I am developing an A* algorithm that is supposed to solve a Missionary and cannibals problem. What i dont understand is what the Heuristic does to make the search less nodes than the Dikstras algorithm.

I understand that the program will search based on the best first by using the heuristic value + current value to determine the possible value, but how does the algorithm know when to stop searching and not branch into other nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The heuristic must guarantee that it is never too high (assuming you are looking for the smallest solution). Therefore, once you have found a complete solution, you know it must be the best. Any incomplete solution (that has already a higher value than your current one, otherwise you would have explored it further) can only be even higher when completed.

Comment: Okay so explore best first with the heuristic and then once you find that specific solution you will then have the optimal one and not have to search anymore?

Comment: Yes, that's how A* works. To be precise, "find" means the solution is expanded as the best one to try next.